# C# Parsing XML and XElement

Tags: c#, xml

I have this code.  Also here is a sample of the XML.   I apologize for any confusion

```
<object type="node" >
    <property name="id" value="1" />
    <property name="name" value="ossvc06_node1" />
      <property name="port_id" value="50050768014062AC" />
      <property name="port_status" value="active" />
      <property name="port_speed" value="4Gb" />
  <property name="port_id" value="50050768013062AC" />
  <property name="port_status" value="active" />
  <property name="port_speed" value="4Gb" />
  <property name="port_id" value="50050768011062AC" />
 <property name="port_status" value="active" />
 <property name="port_speed" value="4Gb" />
 <property name="port_id" value="50050768012062AC" />
 <property name="port_status" value="active" />
 <property name="port_speed" value="4Gb" />
 <property name="hardware" value="8G4" />
 <property name="iscsi_name" value="iqn.1986-03.com.ibm:2145.ossvc06.ossvc06node1" />
 <property name="iscsi_alias" value="" />
 <property name="failover_active" value="no" />
 <property name="failover_name" value="ossvc06_node2" />
 <property name="failover_iscsi_name" value="iqn.1986-       .com.ibm:2145.ossvc06.ossvc06node2" />
 <property name="failover_iscsi_alias" value="" />
 <property name="front_panel_id" value="115286" />
</object>
```

In the input file there are two of these objects of type "Node" each with different values for the property tags.

In this code I am looking for all the objects of type "node" in the incoming XML.  There are 2 of them.  The 'var nodes' statement evaluates correctly.  In the debugger I can see two XElements with what appears to be the proper type and elements in the element list.  However, the statement that gets the elements and assigns them to a list has ChildElements from both of the objects of type "node"  that are in the XML  and I am not sure why.

```
//load the input file
 XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(_InputFile);

//get the object of type 'node'

//this code gives the results expected
// in the debugger each XElement appears to have the proper value and childElements
var nodes = from node in xdoc.Descendants("object")
                        where node.Attribute("type").Value == "node"
                        select node;

foreach (XElement nodelement  in nodes)
{  

    // problem happens here, the child elements from both  nodes get assigned to the list 
    List<XElement> nodeles = nodelement.Elements().ToList();
    Node node = NodeFactory(nodelement);

    // now assign the node to the correct IO group
    var iogrp = SVCClusters[0].IOGroups.Where(io => io.Name == node.IOGroupName);
    if (iogrp.FirstOrDefault().FirstNode == null) { iogrp.FirstOrDefault().FirstNode = node; }
    else { iogrp.FirstOrDefault().SecondNode = node; }

}
```

Comment: I copied and pasted the code.  In my testing the nodelement variable in the foreach refers to the object element, and the nodeles variable contains 2 elements, each refer to the property child element of each object.  Is this what you get.. or expect.  How many items does the nodeles list contain for each iteration?

Comment: this is what is I exptected to happen but in my code, I get in nodeles list childelements from both object elements.  IOW if one object element has a property of type id value 1, and the other has value 2, I see 2 properties of type id, first is value 1 and second is value 2 in nodeles.  there should only be 1

Comment: I added some additional properties.  the ones I am most interested in and that are duplicates are port_id, port_status and port_speed. there should be 4 of each in each object element, but I see 8 in nodeleles

Comment: weird, I pasted your expanded xml twice and wrapped in a root node.  i.e. <root><object>...</object><object>...</object></root>.  I get 22 elements each iteration.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to do the foreach after you've assigned the nodes?  I may be missing something but the .ToList() seems to pull the 22 elements out, duplicates or not.

Comment: out of interest, can you change the var nodes line to  var nodes = xdoc.Descendants("object").Where(node => node.Attribute("type").Value == "node").ToList();  This will execute the query immediately, your version is defered.

Comment: @Sisyphus... yes each object element contains 22 property elements.  What david is experiencing is that 44 elements are returned for each iteration

Comment: @Robert Slaney, that didn't work either.  Try pasting this line in after the nodelels line:  var wwpns = nodelement.XPathSelectElements("//property[@name='port_id']");  you should get back 4 results in the list of results, instead you get back 12, 4 values that aren't even part of the object, the 4 expected ones and the last 4 are from the other node

Comment: the XPath query is executing from the document ROOT (//property).  Remove the // and I get 4 per iteration

Comment: that did it.  thanks.  I didn't realize the // was for document root

Comment: Does that mean your original issue is now resolved ?

Comment: the // axis shortcut can be used to select any descendant of the current node by using ".//".

Comment: so instead of XPathSelectElements("//property[@name='port_id']")  to get to a property on the current node I could just do XPathSelectElements("//[@name='port_id']")  ?  ok never mind, your answer just popped up in the browser.  thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you run this in a console app and tell me what you get

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse("<root><object type=\"node\" ><property name=\"id\" value=\"1\" /><property name=\"name\" value=\"ossvc06_node1\" /></object><object type=\"node\" ><property name=\"id\" value=\"2\" /><property name=\"name\" value=\"ossvc06_node2\" /></object></root>");

        var nodes = xdoc.Descendants("object").Where(node => node.Attribute("type").Value == "node").ToList();

        foreach (XElement nodelement in nodes)
        {
            List<XElement> nodeles = nodelement.Elements().ToList();

            foreach (var node in nodeles)
                Console.WriteLine(node);
        }
    }
```

You should have 4 rows output to the console

Edit---

Original issue was that an XPath expression "//property[@name='port_id']" was being used.  This queries from the document root, not from the current node.

Change the XPath to be either "property[@name='port_id'] or ".//property[@name='port_id']"